# Argument type 'List<Todolist>? Function(QuerySnapshot<Object?>)' can't assigned to parameter type 'List<Todolist> Function(QuerySnapshot<Object?>)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Following error occured for Firebase Cloudstore . I cant map a list function to Stream list todo
The argument type 'List? Function(QuerySnapshot<Object?>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List Function(QuerySnapshot<Object?>)'.

import 'dart:math';

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:todolist/models/model.dart';

class databaseService {
  CollectionReference todosCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Todos");

  Future createNewTools(String title) async {
    await todosCollection.add({
      "title": title,
      "iscomplete": false,
    });
  }

  Future completTask(id) async {
    await todosCollection.doc(id).update({"iscomplete": true});
  }

  Future removeTodo(uid) async {
    await todosCollection.doc(uid).delete();
  }

  List<Todolist>? todoFromFirestore(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot != null) {
      return snapshot.docs.map((e) {
        return Todolist(
                iscomplete: e["iscomplete"],
                title: e["title"],
                id: e.id,
        );
      }).toList();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Stream<List<Todolist>> listTodo(){
    return todosCollection.snapshots().map(todoFromFirestore); //error
  }

  }
```

and the todolist model file:

```
class Todolist {
  String id;
  String title;
  String iscomplete;

  Todolist({required this.id, required this.title, required this.iscomplete, isComplete});
}
```

error:
[image]

Comment: The problem here is that the `map` method can't accept `null` values. Your `todoFromFirestore` signature is `List?` which means that your method may return `null` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  List<Todolist> todoFromFirestore(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot != null) {
      return snapshot.docs.map((e) {
        return Todolist(
                iscomplete: e["iscomplete"],
                title: e["title"],
                id: e.id,
        );
      }).toList();
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

A nullable List is causing the error.
Try This...